# Setting WinXP compatibility mode in the registry by code doesn't work

Tags: windows, registry, windows-xp, compatibility

Under Win7/8, I would like to force the WinXP compatibility mode for a software by adding a value in the registry when installing the software so the end users won't have to set it by hand.

I created a setup.exe that installs the software with all the required files. The setup creates a new string value entry in the registry at this location :

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers]
"C:\\PathToTheApp\\App.exe"="WINXPSP3"
```

If I open the app's properties window (using the explorer), The compatibility mode is checked for all the users but when I run the app the XP mode is not enabled and Windows don't event ask me if the app is allowed to run.

If I disable and re-enable it using the properties window (using the explorer), then it works. When I run the app Windows asks me if the app is allowed to run and apply changes to the computer and the XP compatibility is active. And the registry key above is created by the explorer process.

- I tried restarting the computer after the setup is done but it doesn't work.
- I tried calling *SHChangeNotify()* to notify the new settings to the shell but it doesn't work.
- I tried adding the registry key by hand but it doesn't work.
- The setup asks for the admin rights so it can writes in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.

I searched with googles for a few days but each time I found out that I was supposed to only create the registry value above.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: You obfuscated the *most* important information, bad idea.  Use SysInternals' Process Monitor and change the compat setting with Explorer.  The trace shows you *exactly* what registry key is getting written.  Run it again with your app and compare.  You are liable to learn more about the registry and file system redirector in the process.

Comment: @ Hans Passant: I did use Process Monitor and even Regshot to see what keys are modified. And the explorer modifies the same key my setup does and some PerfLib keys. Perflib keys are supposed to be used with the performance counters. The only differences is that Explorer create the same key several times with the same value each time, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: @HansPassant: Explorer also calls a the QuerySecurityFile but I couldn't find helpful links about it with google.